# What does "Do you even North America?" mean?

Tags: meaning

English isn't my first language and I'm having a problem with understanding the meaning of this question.

Does "Do you even North America?" mean that they're asking if I'm from North America?

Comment: Well, it makes no grammatical sense. *North America* is not a verb (which is what the do-support implies). It could be a catchphrase or an adaptation of one. Do you have a little more context -- more lines of the conversation you can edit into your question?

Comment: This is a meme. As Spehro Pefhany points out in his answer, the original is "Do you even lift?" It was used for comedic effect. Then people started to change the verb, for additional comedic effect. Like, "Do you even drive?" or "Do you even think?" And then people started to change the verb into a noun, for even more comedic effect. Like, "Do you even politics?" or "Do you even feminism?" or "Do you even mathematics?" or "Do you even North America?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the wording of your question, I'm assuming someone told you this phrase (please correct me if I'm wrong).

> ... does "Do you even North America?" mean that they're asking if **I'm** from North America?

Although it is not gramatically correct, I believe it is a play on words, probably a variation from the meme ["*Do you even lift?*"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-you-even-lift)
The phrase could have been used to point out cultural differences (mockingly or in a condescending manner). Maybe you said or did something that "gave you away" as a foreigner.

EDIT: Just yesterday I was talking with North American friends about their culture. For example, how natural it seems to calculate distances in terms of how long it takes to get there by car; to have lawyer ads everywhere; the fact that virtually anything can be deep-fried... You get the idea.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of statement is a form of slang with deep internet origins. Not quite enough context to be sure, but I think they are asking if you are able to behave as a North American would.

Similar phrases such as ["Do you even dog?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnimalsBeingDerps/comments/2215af/do_you_even_dog_bro/) for a dog that acts strangely for a dog are not uncommon. Note that it includes the "Do you even ___?" structure plus the awkward verbing of a noun.

The "Do you even ___" interrogative apparently originated in 2002 [on a bodybuilding forum](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-you-even-lift) in a comment that ended "Do you even lift?". It quickly morphed into "Do you even lift, bro?" to better encapsulate the attitude of the stereotypical meathead weight lifter.

It's probably inappropriate to use this kind of slang when attempting to communicate with someone who is not a native English speaker, or anyone who isn't reasonably computer-literate and also social-media-savvy.

Comment: Putting the entire phrase into a search engine reveals just 2-3 results, relating to a computer game "Do You Even - North America", and no results in relation to urban slang or social media new-speak.

Comment: @Cargill Right, but it's an easily recognizable use of a hackneyed pattern. Searching for "do you even" -lift -dog gives (or so Google claims) millions of results, and most of them (at least the initial ones) are in the "do you even <noun | verb>" pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I just read this interesting article about the "[Do you even...?](http://daily.jstor.org/in-which-we-science-why-nouns-become-verbs-because-language/)" usage on JSTOR Daily.  The following is an extract.

> Consider popular internet memes like “Let me librarian that for you” and “Do you even science, bro?” in which “librarian” and “science” are nouns weirdly disguised as verbs. […] The conversion of nouns into verbs is not actually a new phenomenon. Some call it **“verbing,”** which sounds like a new dance craze, while linguistic nerds call it **denominalization**. Benjamin Franklin preferred to call it “awkward and abominable.”

[…]

> **Why We Verb On the Internet**
>
> Verbing can be a faster and fresher way to convey tired information. And it can do so with a sense of humor and surprise. The internet and social media have made it easier than ever to share neologisms, but it’s not just about creating new words. It’s also about creating new forms. ... If you don’t know the internet meme **“Do you even lift, bro?”** (which expresses skepticism for someone’s knowledge), you won’t really get the **“Do you even science, bro?”** meme. These memes tell us exactly how we’re supposed to understand these new verbs, as though we were dealing with a more concrete noun.
>
> While many of these verbs may not last, it’s evident that verbing under the influence of memes has changed the way we talk. It may be weird, but somehow it ends up working. Because language.
>
> <sub>BY CHI LUU  MARCH 9, 2016</sub>

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. If your linked resource answers the original question, please edit your post to summarize it and provide an explanation. If not, it is better-suited as a comment, such as this one, which you will be able to leave once you have earned sufficient site reputation points. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. As links are often unstable, link-only answers are discouraged regardless of the quality of the resource.

Comment: As choster says, please sum up or quote the main points of the article here. Link rot is a thing. Once the link no longer works, your answer becomes utterly useless. If you quote the relevant bits, it will persist to be helpful.